# How to Count Word or Phrase Density?

Tags: c#, winforms, text

I'm writing a method to search for counting most used words or phrases. (2 and 3 word phrases).
If there is a three-word result, I do not want it to return the two-word results.

Here, an example txt:

*"He received his academic teaching diploma from the Swiss Federal Polytechnic School in Zürich in 1900. In 1911 to Charles University in Prague before returning to the Federal Polytechnic School in 1912."*

Result:

```
Federal Polytechnic School [2]
Polytechnic School in [2]
Federal Polytechic [2]
Polytechnic School [2]
School in [2]
```

Code:

```
            void anahtarKelimeAnalizi2(string metin)
        {

            string txt = metin;

            string[] words = txt.Split(',', '.', ';', ' ', '\n', '\r');

            words = words.Select(t => t.Trim()).Where(t => t.Trim() != string.Empty).ToArray();

            const int MaxPhraseLength = 3;

            Dictionary<string, int> Counts = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            for (int phraseLen = MaxPhraseLength; phraseLen >= 2; phraseLen--)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < words.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    string[] phrase = GetPhrase(words, i, phraseLen);
                    string sphrase = string.Join(" ", phrase);

                    int index = FindPhraseIndex(words, i + phrase.Length, phrase);

                    if (index > -1)
                    {
                        if (!Counts.ContainsKey(sphrase))
                            Counts.Add(sphrase, 1);

                        Counts[sphrase]++;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var foo in Counts)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(foo.Key + " [" + foo.Value+"]");
            }
        }

        static string[] GetPhrase(string[] words, int startpos, int len)
        {
            return words.Skip(startpos).Take(len).ToArray();
        }

        static int FindPhraseIndex(string[] words, int startIndex, string[] matchWords)
        {
            for (int i = startIndex; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                int j;

                for (j = 0; j < matchWords.Length && (i + j) < words.Length; j++)
                    if (matchWords[j] != words[i + j])
                        break;

                if (j == matchWords.Length)
                    return startIndex;
            }

            return -1;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is this not just a case of for your loop being >=2 so it is including the 2 word length... If you set it to just >2 does it work? Just a thought, don't have time to copy your code and try it at the moment.

Comment: @RyanThomas Yes, It works for this text but I have very long texts actually and I need two-word phrases too.